# Texas Hold'em Poker odds with many opponents - impossible to compute?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

I'm starting to wonder if it is even possible to analytically calculate the odds of beating multiple opponents in a Texas Hold'em Poker game.

Let's start with an example to explain the complexity of the problem. Assume N+1 players, myself included, are all-in at a one-deck Texas Hold'em Poker game. The 5 cards on the table are as follow: 3-spades / 3-diamonds / 4-hearts / 5-hearts / 9-hearts

My hole cards are: 2-hearts / 6-spades

Therefore, I have a 6-high straight. There are N other players with unknown hole cards. What are the odds that I will win the pot?

I started by counting all the hole cards that could beat mine:

- four-of-a-kind [(3,3), 1 possible hand]
- full-house [(3,4), (3,5), (3,9), 2*3 = 6 possible hands each for a total of 18]
- flush [(heart, heart), choose(9,2) = 36 possible hands]
- 7-high straight [(6,7), 3*4 = 12 possible hands including 1 that was counted in the (heart, heart)]

Therefore, out of the choose(45,2) = 990 possible hole cards (since there's only 45 cards remaining in the deck), 66 would beat my hand. This would give me a 924/990 = 93.3% chance of winning against a single opponent.

The problem is, what are the odds that I'm beating every one of the N players around the table? The probabilities depend on each other in very complex ways: for example, if Player 1 has one of the 924 losing hands, the probability of the others players of having a losing hands depend on the Player 1's hand (if he has a (2,3) as hole cards, then the other players' odds of having a full-house and four-of-a-kind diminishes, or if he has a single heart, then the other players' odds of having a flush diminishes, etc.).

I tried many things for a while, but I can't seem to find a solution to find an analytical answer without resorting to Monte Carlo simulations. We'd either need to brute force all possible sequences of hole cards pairs (which is 543 billion possibilities for only N=4 players), or keep track of all past hole cards pairs (which would require about 10*300 bytes of memory).

The closest thing I've found online was [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989641/in-texas-holdem-poker-is-the-ranking-according-to-chance-of-beating-1-opponent) that states "no one can compute the exact probabilities of beating 8 random opponents' hands (a full game is usually 9 players)."

This seems like a very simple problem: **You're drawing cards from a deck in pairs. What are the odds that after N draws, at least one of the pairs was in an arbitrary list of pairs? Is this computation truly impossible?**

Comment: We don't have to consider all possible sequences of hole cards, just all combinations of winning pairs.  In the example you give that is at most $$\sum_{n=1}^8\binom{66}n=6,662,925,947$$  (This assumes $N=8$.)  Of course, it's really less than that since many of the pairs have a card in common.  Then we use inclusion-exclusion.  You can probably cut the the computation short at some point too.  Surely the event that all $8$ opponents have a beating pair is negligible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this... if we want the odds that no one has a winning pair, don't you need to calculate all combinations of losing pairs, not winning pairs? The conditional probabilities need to be calculated for the cases where all the players drew a losing pair.


For 4 players, this would be choose(924, 4) = 30 billion combinations, all with their specific conditional probabilities.

Comment: The probability that everyone has a losing pair is $1$ minus the probability that someone has a winning pair.  If we count how many possible sets of one winning pair ($66$) two winning pairs ($\binom{66}2-$overlaps) and so on, this is a simple application of the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  The entire difficulty is in counting those sets, because of the overlaps.

Comment: You are right, but this would work pretty poorly in a generic case. I mostly gave that example as a way to illustrate the complexity of the set counting. If there's 100 winning pairs, then we have 186 billion calculations. Seeing as there can be as high as 495 winning/losing pairs, we're quickly leaving the realm of possible calculations. Would a solution to calculating the odds for a generic case (with all the cards but my opponents' revealed on the table) really be impossible?

Comment: In a totally general case, it's probably out of reach, but the more winning pairs there are, the less likely that you're still in the game.  I plan to try some calculations tomorrow, to see when the probabilities become negligible for this example.  (I'm sure if one knows the probability to the nearest whole percent, that's as much as any poker player needs.)  I've never played Texas hold 'em, so I can't make reasonable examples of my own.  If I have any success, I'll ask you for some other realistic examples tomorrow.